# What is the difference between 0Auth and JWT in Azure AD the best practice for using access tokens in Azure AD?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am a newbie to Azure AD. What is the best practice for using Azure AD access tokens?

What is the difference between an 0Auth and JWT token and which one should I use to follow best practices?

I used the below code to get the Token. Do I need to convert it to an 0Auth Token?

```
var AzureData = await DependencyService.Get<IAuthenticator>()
                      .Authenticate(App.tenanturl, App.GraphResourceUri, App.ApplicationID, App.ReturnUri);
                    App.AuthenticationResult = AzureData;

var userToken =  Azuredata.AccessToken;
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Nope, nothing to convert.  What’s your real goal ?

Comment: @spottedmahn, is above code correct to get accesstoken? I m confused which is the current practice now: use Oauth or JWT token to access authorized OData. Is JWT replacing Oauth?

Comment: I would say a JWT is an implementation detail of OAuth.  OAuth uses JWTs to send the security information.

Comment: Not sure if the above code is correct.  Not sure what you are trying to accomplish...

Comment: My task is to get accessToken from AzureAD. My question is this JWT token can be used in HttpClient for GET/POST/DEL/UPDATE instead of OAuth Token for OData webservice.  Assume above Code is correct that an accessToken is returned.

Comment: Yes, it can be used with HttpClient for those verbs

Answer (score 4):

JWT is a type of Token, and OAuth is a Framework.

JWT (JSON Web Tokens) is just a token format, it defines a compact and self-contained mechanism for transmitting data between parties in a way that can be verified and trusted because it is digitally signed.

Oauth is an authentication framework, where it has a general procedures and setups defined by framework. JWT can be used as a mechanism inside OAuth. You do not need to convert your token.

Use JWT when...

- Federation is desired. For example, you want to use Azure AD as the token issuer, and then use Apigee Edge as the token validator. With JWT, an app can authenticate to Azure AD, receive a token, and then present that token to Apigee Edge to be verified. (Same works with Google Sign-In. Or Paypal. Or Salesforce.com. etc)
- Asynchrony is required. For example, you want the client to send in a request, and then store that request somewhere, to be acted on by a separate system "later". That separate system will not have a synchronous connection to the client, and it may not have a direct connection to a central token dispensary. a JWT can be read by the asynchronous processing system to determine whether the work item can and should be fulfilled at that later time. This is, in a way, related to the Federation idea above. Be careful here, though: JWT expire. If the queue holding the work item does not get processed within the lifetime of the JWT, then the claims should no longer be trusted.

Use OAuth when...

- There is no federation. The issuer of the token is the same party that validates the token. All API requests bearing the token will go through the token dispensary.
  There is no need or desire to allow the holder of the token to examine the claims within the token.
- When you wish to unilaterally allow token revocation. It is not possible to revoke JWT. They expire when they are marked to expire at creation time.

See [this thread](https://community.apigee.com/questions/21139/jwt-vs-oauth.html) for more details.